# Give title in pandas dataframe that export to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have 6 dataframes (named `a` to `f`), that I want to import to ms.excel, to make this easier to read I want to give lable of each dataframe, I try to work [with cell notation](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html), but i got error mesage, here's my code:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Summary Data Request 8 weeks.xlsx')
a.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1)
b.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol=7)
c.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=11)
d.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=11, startcol=6)
e.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=21)
f.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=21, startcol=6)
writer.write('A1', 'Retail Kelontong')
writer.write('G1', 'Pulsa')
writer.write('A11', 'Minimarket')
writer.write('G11', 'Retail dengan barcode')
writer.write('A21', 'Retail dengan barcode 2')
writer.write('G21', 'Food and Beverage')
writer.save()
```

Here's the error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-2354b95670c9> in <module>()
      6 e.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=21)
      7 f.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=21, startcol=6) 
----> 8 writer.write('A1', 'Retail Kelontong')
      9 writer.write('G1', 'Pulsa')
     10 writer.write('A11', 'Minimarket')


AttributeError: '_XlsxWriter' object has no attribute 'write'
```

I still don't know what I did wrong, I try to change writer to `Sheet1` and the error message is

```
name 'Sheet1' is not defined
```

I lack of idea what to try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation you have to use the `write` method of the sheet, not the writer:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Summary Data Request 8 weeks.xlsx')
a.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1)
b.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol=7)
c.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=11)
d.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=11, startcol=6)
e.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=21)
f.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=21, startcol=6)
# Get sheet1
sheet1 = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
sheet1.write('A1', 'Retail Kelontong')
sheet1.write('G1', 'Pulsa')
sheet1.write('A11', 'Minimarket')
sheet1.write('G11', 'Retail dengan barcode')
sheet1.write('A21', 'Retail dengan barcode 2')
sheet1.write('G21', 'Food and Beverage')
writer.save()
```